# Why was ActionBarActivity deprecated

Tags: android, android-actionbar, deprecated, android-actionbaractivity

I installed Android Studio freshly and I begun coding an activity to extend `ActionBarActivity` and it showed that it was deprecated. So how else do I set up an actionbar for my activity.
Also the Getting Started Training uses the `ActionBarActivity` without making reference that it has been deprecated.

Comment: [AppCompat Activity](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/how-to-add-toolbar-to-an-activity-which-doesn-t-extend-appcompatactivity-a07c026717b3)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797172/whats-the-enhancement-of-appcompatactivity-over-actionbaractivity

Comment: As of appcompat-v7-r21.1.0 the logic somewhat changed and on top of that `ActionBarActivity` is now `AppCompatActivity`. There's no difference between these two from your point of view.

Comment: ActionBarActivity is removed since support library 26.0.0-beta2 https://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/26.0.0-beta2/changes/alldiffs_index_removals.html

Answer (score 121, accepted):

ActionBar is deprecated ever since `Toolbar` was introduced. `Toolbar` can be seen as a 'superset' of any action bar. So the 'old' `ActionBar` is now an example of a `Toolbar`. If you want similar functionality, but without deprecation warnings do the following:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
if (toolbar != null) {
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

You need to define the `Toolbar` in your layout xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

With this new functionality you can create your own custom `ActionBar` and let Android do the heavy lifting. Just create your own custom view that extends from `Toolbar`.

---

Also, you should use `AppCompatActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`, it was introduced in the latest version of the appcompat library. So dont forget to update gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
```

Comment: Is it as simple as swapping out `extends ActionBarActivity` with `extends AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: Internally there are quite some changes, but the interface is identical. So yeah, it is as easy as just replacing the type of activity.

Comment: sucks that the Android Studio wizard still extends ActionBarActivity and then tells you it is deprecated. Do they even communicate internally @Google?

Comment: Not the Perfect Solution. Your given answer for ActionBar not for ActionBarActivity. I will go with @DroidMind Solution

Comment: Great, more work again. Same as their design to encourage everyone to use Fragments. Google's design principles are great for companies that have 10 people working on the same app.

Answer (score 71):

Here is the answer from the [post in Android developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html):

**"ActionBarActivity has been deprecated in favor of the new AppCompatActivity.**"

You can read more about it there.

Answer (score 8):

*This answer give a simple way to Eliminate the error message.
You can see as an add to others'.*

> When we change the parent Activity class: `ActionBarActivity` to `AppCompatActivity` the error message will disappear.

You can click [here](http://inducesmile.com/android-tutorials-for-nigerian-developer/how-to-fix-android-support-v7-actionbaractivity-is-deprecated/) for more info.

Comment: does this seem like an add to anyone else?