# How to include Action Bar Activity in android Java

Tags: java, android

I have a an android java class which I am extends another activity , however I would also like to include my ActionbarActivity as well. The code I have below does not seem to do the trick.

```
public class ExpandableListMainActivity extends ExpandableListActivity   implements ActionBarActivity
```

Comment: Make ExpandableListMainActivity extend AppCompatActivity.  It's not an interface, and Java doesn't have multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated.You should use `AppCompatActivity` instead.

[Why was ActionBarActivity deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877692/why-was-actionbaractivity-deprecated)

Secondly, `extends ExpandableListActivity implements ActionBarActivity` won't work.

Use it like this instead :

```
public class ExpandableListMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

**For reasons:** [Implements vs extends: When to use? What's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839131/implements-vs-extends-when-to-use-whats-the-difference)

- > implements is for implementing an **interface**
  >
  > extends is for extending a **class**.

So, that's not an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity should extends `AppCompactActivity` and then you should declare an `ExpandableListView` in XML layout for the Activity.

In `onCreate` of the Activity : `setContentView(that_xml_file);`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ExpandableListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```