# NullPointer when get ActionBar

Tags: android

I used the following code from [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us) to change the background color of ActionBar:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000000")));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
//More codes here
}
```

I know that I should use `getSupportActionBar()` when using `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`. I don't use support v7. I am working in andoridx environment and I have imported the followings but I am not sure if these relating to the problem  :

```
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.app.ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)'
>   on a null object reference

Comment: You should call `getActionBar` after you've set the content view, not before.

Comment: I moved it after content view but no change @Edric

Comment: Did you move the line which sets the background drawable as well?

Comment: Yes I moved both lines. I guess the problem is new syntax of andoridx.@Edric

Comment: It's probably because you should've extended `ActionBarActivity` instead of `Activity`.

Comment: It seems that `ActionBarActivity` was deprecated and removed in v26 of the Support Library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877692/why-was-actionbaractivity-deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by setting up the environment as the following:

adding:

```
import static androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR;
```

changing

```
extends Activity
```

to

```
extends AppCompatActivity
```

and shifting to support package by:

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`

after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: I am not using support package

Comment: use the line `getActionBar()` after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
setContentView initiate Layout which will generate ActionBar