# ActionBarActivity is deprecated

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, deprecated

Actually there is no problem. Project compiles and runs. But I can't understand what is mean strikeout class name (Android Studio tells that there is deprecated code is used)[image]. Can anybody explain?

Answer (score 330, accepted):

Since the version *22.1.0*, the class `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated. You should use `AppCompatActivity`.

Read [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) and [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html) for more information.

Comment: they could have updated the activity templates. sigh...

Comment: Now 1,000,000 will waste 5 minutes fixing this because somebody at google did not update the template. That´s 5 million minutes lost, to be conservative.

Comment: The template was updated in Android Studio 1.3-dev

Comment: Because google you know

Answer (score 40):

According to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=49&v=5Be2mJzP-Uw) of Android Developers you should only make two changes

[image]

Comment: Other changes may be necessary as outlined in that video.  The two changes shown here are merely the most basic changes.  It is also important to include the proper dependency for existing projects -- as outlined in that video.

Answer (score 8):

android developers documentation says : "Updated the AppCompatActivity as the base class for activities that use the support library action bar features. This class replaces the deprecated ActionBarActivity."

checkout [changes for Android Support Library, revision 22.1.0 (April 2015)](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)