# I keep getting an error in android studio

Tags: android, android-actionbaractivity

The error is android.support.v7.ActionBarActivity is deprecated. Does anyone know if it affects my game or how to fix it? Thank in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActionBarActivity is deprecated (Android Studio)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890530/actionbaractivity-is-deprecated-android-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `ActionBarActivity` with `AppCompatActivity`.