# Android Studio : All of a sudden cannot resolve symbol 'ActionBarActivity'

Tags: android, android-studio

I am really new to android programming. I have been using Android Studio 1.2.1.1 for the last couple of weeks and made very simple apps(basically learning). And today I open any project it always shows

**cannot resolve symbol 'ActionBarActivity'**

I have tried the other solutions offered in other answers here.
I did almost all of them. I imported Google Play Services, Google Support Repository, Invalidated caches and restarted.But nothing seems to help. And as expected I am unable to run the app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ActionBarActivity is deprecated, check this:

[ActionBarActivity is deprecated android studio][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890530/actionbaractivity-is-deprecated-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

`ActionBarActivity` is deprecated i.e dead. You should instead use `AppCompatActivity`. See below links for details

https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/LNyDnnBYJ8r

[ActionBarActivity is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890530/actionbaractivity-is-deprecated-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

According to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=49&v=5Be2mJzP-Uw) of Android Developers you should only make two changes:

**1. AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application android:theme="@style/**Theme.App.Compact**">
```

**2. Change every Activity with ActionBarActivity like this**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```