# NullPointerException on actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean) in Api version 22

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

I am using Actionbar in my App, it working fine below api 22.

using `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`

use below code for Action bar

```
public void initActionBar() {
           actionBar = getActionBar();
           actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
           actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
           actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
           actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
           actionBar.setTitle("Rides");
           actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.menu);
           actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(newColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange)));
           actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}
```

App Theme in style.xml

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/list_activated_background</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">55dip</item>
</style>
```

When run same In version 22 get below error

**LogCat Error**

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at com.holachef.android.chef_android.activity.HomeActivity.initActionBar(HomeActivity.java:160)
            at com.holachef.android.chef_android.activity.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:62)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

use android studio for this, same code in eclips run successfully on version 22, Is issue related with android studio.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which activity are you using? Activity? ActionBarActivity? or AppCompatActivity?

Answer (score 1):

**You must extend AppCompatActivity instead of FragmentActivity to have Actionbar with fragments.**

If you're using the v7 appcompat library, your activity should instead extend **AppCompatActivity**, which is a subclass of FragmentActivity (for more information, read Adding the Action Bar).

Still you can try this,

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

More detail you can found here. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

*And please switch to Material Theme rather than using the old Holo Theme.*

Comment: friend ActionBarActivity is deprecated so its not good idea to use it. see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890530/actionbaractivity-is-deprecated-android-studio

Comment: Use AppCompatActivity instead.

Comment: @OP if my solution, solved your issue, then you should mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio, the support libraries are all handled by Gradle now. So go to this file:

[image]

Now pay attention to the parts I highlighted in red. Try playing around withe the "minSdkVersion" and rebuild gradle.
[image]