# Cannot resolve symbol ActionBarActivity in Android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android

I can't resolve symbol and so I'm getting loads of other errors. Please help, I have seen that early versions or Android had this problem is don't know what's the problem now?

Comment: Check your support repository in android sdk.. update if available

Comment: It is installed and there are no updates available.

Comment: May this help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316055/actionbaractivity-cannot-resolve-a-symbol

Comment: Hey. Thanks but I think i will try to use the solution that includes importing the Google play services library.

Answer (score 4):

`ActionbarActivity` has been [deprecated](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html) since Android Support Library version *22.1.0*, released in April 2015.
Use `AppCompatActivity` instead.

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29890590/8303038).